# Retrieving Data from a Related Table Via Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework Model with four tables, the only two we need to be concerned with here are [AtmAccounts] and [Transactions]. [AtmAccounts] has the following attributes: [Id -Primary Key], [AccountNumber], [AccountBalance], [UserId] and [AccTypeId]. Transactions has the following: [Id- Primary Key], [TransAmount], [TransDate],[AtmAccountId - Navigation Property] and [TransTypeId].

I want to,  get a list of Transactions for a specific account and display them on the screen. For this, I need to grab all records from the Transactions table which correspond to the AtmAccountId stored in AtmAccounts. How do I get going with this?

Comment: `db.Transactions.Where(s=>s.AtmAccountId==someAccountId")` ?

Comment: @JayRoberts does the above work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you removed the relation, your foreign key relation should already be in your entity model.  In your code Intellisense should show this, for example:

```
var myList = (from x in db.AtmAccounts
             where x.Id==myspecifiedid
             select x.Transactions).ToList();
```

should give you the associated transactions for the specified AtmAccount.